# problem integrating flex with spring

Tags: apache-flex, spring

cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'flex:remoting-destination

i got this error when i tried to build my file 
i wrote the 'flex:remoting-destination' in a web-application-config file 
can any one help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to declare the flex namespace.
Paste this at the top of your web-application-config.xml (noting the **xmlns:flex** part):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:flex="http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/flex/spring-flex-1.0.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

i just want to add little information to @bart

it will work only when the version of the spring flex is matched..

for these shchema defination version number is important

for spring flex 1.5.2 you should give the version as 1.5 instead of 1.0

similarly spring 3.2.1 you should give 3.2 instead of 2.5